# Celery ignores Django settings.py variables

Tags: django, celery

I have setup a test Django environment for production on an Ubuntu 20.04 Sever using following this guide: [Deploying Django](https://djangodeployment.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Specifically, I have placed the Django project in:

```
/opt/mydangoproject/
                   celery.py
                   celery_config.py
                   settings.py
                   etc
```

and I have an additional 'override' settings.py which holds the 'secrets' specifically  in this case the celery login variable RABBITMQ_BROKER it is located in:

```
/etc/opt/mydangoproject/
                       settings.py
```

I have tested this configuration and I have confirmed the settings in /etc/opt/mydangoproject/ are available to the Django environment, however, they are not picked up by celery. I have confirmed this by placing the RABBITMQ_BROKER login variable in the main settings.py (/opt/mydangoproject/) and celery is able to access it.

My celery.py file:

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mydangoproject.settings')

app = Celery('mydangoproject')

default_config = 'mydangoproject.celery_config'

app.config_from_object(default_config)
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

My celery_config.py file:

```
from django.conf import settings

broker_url = settings.RABBITMQ_BROKER
worker_send_task_event = False
task_ignore_result = True
task_time_limit = 600
task_acks_late = True
worker_prefetch_multiplier = 10
worker_cancel_long_running_tasks_on_connection_loss = True
broker_pool_limit = None
```

The settings.py in /etc/opt/mydjangoproject/ :

```
from mydangoproject.settings import *

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [‘blah’]

RABBITMQ_BROKER = 'amqp://wabbitadmin:somepassword@somepassword@webserver:5672/mydangoproject'

DATABASES = {

    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': ‘blah’,
        'USER': ‘blah’,
        'PASSWORD': ‘somepassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
  }

STATIC_ROOT = '/var/cache/mydangoproject/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/opt/mydangoproject/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

My questions are:

1. why can't celery access the RabbitMQ login variable.
2. How do I fix it?

Comment: Did you mean myd**j**angoproject?

Answer (score 0):

Change the variable name to ***`CELERY_BROKER_URL`*** will work as the Celery looking for the settings variable in the following syntax - `<NAMESPACE_NAME>_<SETTINGS_VARIABLE>`

Comment: Hi Jpg, I changed RABBITMQ_BROKER to CELERY_BROKER_URL but it's still not seeing the login variable.